# How would I go about editing a message sent by a a discord bot? But only when reacted to by a user with a certain role?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to setup a bug report system. I have the token system and everything for it, however I need to know how to have the bot edit a message when it is reacted to by a user with a particular role, which for this sake is named 'Debugger'

Comment: What problem are you having specifically? Have you made any attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event you want to listen to is `client.messageReactionAdd`. Be aware, that it will not listen to non-cached messages. To listen to older messages, you must enable [partials](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html), like so:

```
//top of your code
const client = new Discord.Client({partials: [`MESSAGE`, `CHANNEL`, `REACTION`]});
.
.
.
```

This will allow you to receive events for partial messages. In order to get *full* message from partial, you need to fetch it:

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async msgReaction => {
    let msg = msgReaction.message;
//note that messageReactionAdd event returns MessageReaction object, not Message.
//this line makes it simpler to write code.
    if (msg.partial) await msg.fetch().catch();
    //
    //rest of your reaction handler goes here
    //
});
```

You will be able to figure out the rest by reading the documentation.